# Is tax cryptocurrency that rewards holders of the token with tax fees halal or haram

Tags: halal-haram

If you invest in a cryptocurrency that taxes the users a percentage of all buy, sell and transfer transactions then distributes the fees from the taxes to all users of the ecosystem haram or halal.